# Высота строки состояния

Tags: android

Хочу чтоб выезжающая шторка не перекрывала строку состояния

Нашел что высота строки состояния зависит от размера экрана:

        240x320 - 20px 

        320x480 - 25px 

        480х800+ - 38px

Вопрос по реализации, есть ли какой нибудь атрибут, чтоб можно было  сразу в макете, учесть все размеры? 

 Например  ?android:attr/actionBarSize

Или такого атрибута нет и надо просто забить все возможные варианты через dimens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Высота строки состояния до API 23 составляла 25dp, после   24dp. Перечислять все варианты не лучший способ. Лучше использовать такой метод :

`int height = 0;
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      if (resourceId > 0) {
          height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
      }`